# Android studio: JUNIT test, everytime I select to run single method, it keeps running the entire package test folder

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, junit4, junit5

I am trying to run unit test from android studio. I select Run "methodnametest" and it runs the entire package test.  What to do? I just want to run methodnametest method.

Configuration:

Test kind: method
repeat: once
class: unittestclass
method: methodnametest

vm options: -ea
working directory: path/to/app

enrivonment variables: empty
use classpath of module: app
jre: default
shorten command line: user-local default: none

before launch: gradle-aware make:
gradle-aware make.